# URI of Azure Web Jobs output file with node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-webjobs

Today I started using the Azure Web Jobs running a node.js script which outputs a json file in the same directory. I'd like to consume that file using http now, however I can't figure out what the right uri is.
I figured it must be similar to where the logs are (which btw. tell me that the job ran successfully), but I can't seem to find the json file.
Shouldn't it be something like this?
https://SiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net/JobName/output.json

EDIT: 
I just opened the site using Webmatrix, and though I can find the job files (under /App_Data/jobs/triggered/JobName), it seems like the json file wasn't saved though the log says so. Anyone knows if you can save files in a webjob like this?

```
fs.writeFile(outputFilename, JSON.stringify(output, null, 4), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("JSON saved to " + outputFilename);
    }
});
```

Btw. you have to edit the Web.config if you want to server static JSON with Azure:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the file is not next to the WebJob's binaries is that before the WebJob is invoked it is first copied to a temporary directory (`%temp%\jobs\triggered\jobName\randomName`) and is run from there, this way no file is locked and you can update the WebJob's binaries at any time.

The appropriate path to use when persisting a file with a WebJob is using the **WEBROOT_PATH** environment variable as it has the path to your wwwroot.

If you want this file to only be accessible privately (as wwwroot is publicly visible), you can go up one level, for example: `%WEBROOT_PATH%/../output.json`.

Another option is to use: `d:\home`, for context wwwroot is at: `d:\home\site\wwwroot`.

To access that file use the following url: https://SiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net/vfs/site/output.json and you'll need to provide your deployment credentials.

Comment: This will work, but you really shouldn't be writing files to your web site's file system. Write it to blob storage instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to achieve what I wanted using the uri like this:
var outputFilename = 'd:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\output.json';
%WEBROOT_PATH% did not work for me (I propably used it the wrong way...)
@MarkRendle what are the advantages of using blob in this case? Would it still be possible to consume the json using a simple http reqeust to a uri?

Comment: @Thomas, it appears you cannot use the environment variable as part of a regular path. (At least not with the Path class methods I tried.) However, you can get the value via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBROOT_PATH")` or resolve your strings using `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs#webjob-working-directory) `in place` option is enabled by default for Node.js scripts therefore the script isn't copied to a temp location. However, this is an old answer so it's more than likely the behaviour has changed (or the OP was overriding this).

Comment: Attempting to write to `WEBROOT_PATH` results in `UnauthorizedAccessException`.